# Sorting a json array based on a key using knockout

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, arrays

I have a `jsonarray` something like this:

```
  var jsonarr= [{"displayName":"Rachita Jain","phoneNumbers":[{"value":"(787) 989-6756"},{"value":"
    (897) 867-4666"}]},{"displayName":"Akanksha Mittal","phoneNumbers":[{"value":"(678) 456-4677"}]}]
```

I want to sort this using knockout based on `displayName`.

Answer (score 1):

Use sort function array:

```
var jsonarr = [{
    "displayName": "Rachita Jain",
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "value": "(787) 989-6756"
    }, {
        "value": "(897) 867-4666"
    }]
}, {
    "displayName": "Akanksha Mittal",
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "value": "(678) 456-4677"
    }]
}];



jsonarr.sort(function (item1, item2) { return (item1.displayName > item2.displayName) ? 1 : -1 });

console.log(jsonarr);
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8gDk/)